# Error when running ng build --prod: JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, angular

When running `ng build --prod` I get the following error, how do I resolve this?

```sh
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to update the max_old_space_size and build your project by running this command

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

or set this value in package.json

```
"build": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod"
```

and run

```
npm run build
```

Comment: Okay, but what is the difference between node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod and ng build --prod.  Why it is not working with ng build --prod then?

Comment: node --max_old_space_size=8192 is used to assign more memory for running node.js so it won't run out of memory otherwise they are the same commands

Comment: Thanks hanini! That's really helpful.. But it's just same as hard coding the values at compile instead the allocation of memory which actually happens at runtime.