# npm - How to set max-old-space-size in npm

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am getting the below error while building the angular project,

CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

I have seen somewhere that configuring max-old-space-size in npm will solve the issue. But I don't know how to set it. I am using Windows OS & there are two npm files inside the nodejs installation folder (C:\Program Files\nodejs), npm & npm.cmd. First line inside the npm.cmd file is "Created by npm, please don't edit manually". So I am not supposed to edit this file & I have to configure max-old-space-size inside npm file. But I don't where in this file I have to configure it. My npm file looks like below,

```
#!/bin/sh
(set -o igncr) 2>/dev/null && set -o igncr; # cygwin encoding fix

basedir=`dirname "$0"`

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

NODE_EXE="$basedir/node.exe"
if ! [ -x "$NODE_EXE" ]; then
  NODE_EXE=node
fi

NPM_CLI_JS="$basedir/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js"

case `uname` in
  *MINGW*)
    NPM_PREFIX=`"$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" prefix -g`
    NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS="$NPM_PREFIX/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js"
    if [ -f "$NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS" ]; then
      NPM_CLI_JS="$NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS"
    fi
    ;;
  *CYGWIN*)
    NPM_PREFIX=`"$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" prefix -g`
    NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS="$NPM_PREFIX/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js"
    if [ -f "$NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS" ]; then
      NPM_CLI_JS="$NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS"
    fi
    ;;
esac

"$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" "$@"
```

Comment: May this work for you https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit

Comment: Also what is the version of your node and npm?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52161175/ng-build-prod-error-fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-jav/52161368#52161368

Comment: @angular/cli: 1.4.10
node: 6.10.3
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.1.3
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.11
@angular/common: 4.1.3
@angular/compiler: 4.1.3
@angular/core: 4.1.3
@angular/forms: 4.1.3
@angular/http: 4.1.3
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.1
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.
@angular/platform-browser-dynam
@angular/router: 4.1.3
@angular/cli: 1.4.10
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.3
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
typescript: 2.2.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ng build --prod error : FATAL ERROR: CALL\_AND\_RETRY\_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52161175/ng-build-prod-error-fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-jav) - linked question was asked first and already has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Possibly you could try this,

```
> npm run start --node-flags --max-old-space-size=512 --no-warnings

> node --max-old-space-size=250 `which npm` some_npm_command
```

Comment: can you please elaborate it. Where I have to run this command ?

Comment: This works fine for a temporary solution, but there must be a way to set this globally so we don't have to give max old size every time

Comment: This also can be set into your windows profile or .bashrc on linux as alias as 
`alias npm='node --max_old_space_size=8000 /usr/bin/npm'`

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue but i had to increase docker memory size.

[image: Docker Screenshot]